# There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project being built "AMD64"

Tags: uwp, release-builds

I am getting the following error when creating a store package for my UWP app:

> There was a mismatch between the processor architecture of the project
>   being built "AMD64" and the processor architecture of the reference
>   "C:\user.nuget\packages\ksemenenko.googleanalytics\1.0.3.2\lib\UAP10\Plugin.GoogleAnalytics.dll",
>   "x86". This mismatch may cause runtime failures. Please consider
>   changing the targeted processor architecture of your project through
>   the Configuration Manager so as to align the processor architectures
>   between your project and references, or take a dependency on
>   references with a processor architecture that matches the targeted
>   processor architecture of your project.

I have opened the Configuration Manager and  made sure the configs are aligned with the architectures: ARM/ARM, x64/x64, x86/x86.

Does anybody know how to "align the processor architectures between your project and references" for "AMD64"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the 3rd party DLL you are consuming. The way it's compiled won't work in an x64 process. You have to stick with x86 until they have fixed this. I see you have already opened a bug in their GitHub repo.

If you take a look with ildasm at the DLL included in the nuget package you will see this hint:

```
.module Plugin.GoogleAnalytics.dll
// MVID: {A0116946-EA05-4F0C-8BE9-A44B1EEF77BD}
.imagebase 0x10000000
.file alignment 0x00000200
.stackreserve 0x00100000
.subsystem 0x0003       // WINDOWS_CUI
.corflags 0x00000003    //  ILONLY 32BITREQUIRED
// Image base: 0x07EF0000
```

Comment: Yep. So for now you can only build x86 version of your using that library, until they have fixed it. However, the x86 version should run on your AMD64 system.

Comment: Thanks for the info Stefan! One more question: you refer to "my AMD system" But I run a Macbook pro with Parallels for Windows with Intel processor, according to system settings. Where does the AMD come from?

Comment: I mean your system running the 64-bit version of Windows. The point was that the 32-bit compiled version (x86) of your app will also run on the 64-bit OS.

Comment: Ok thanks again. I just found another google analytics package for uwp that works correctly. The downside is that I now can't share my netstandard lib that I use for my android and iOS apps with uwp. I had a similar issue with messagepack. I guess netstandard isn't so x-platform as I hoped, at least UWP has some limitations.

Comment: Hope you can get a fix from ksemenenko soon. Meanwhile please mark this as answered so we can close it out.